# Таблица умножения на JS(стилизация)

Tags: javascript, css

Доброго времени суток уважаемые! Подскажите как можно сделать чтобы после вывода в консоль таблица выравнивалась по правому краю. Пробовал добавить стили oneRow.style.float = 'right', textAlign = 'right' и другие. Выдает ошибку. Подскажите пожалуйста.

```js
let oneRow = '';
const multiply = (number) => {
    for (let i = 1; i <= number; i++) {
        for (let j = 1; j < 11; j++) {
            oneRow += (j*i) + " ";       
        }
    console.log(oneRow);
        oneRow = '';
    } 

}

multiply(5);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте использовать [`padStart()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart)

```js
let oneRow = '';
const multiply = (number) => {
    for (let i = 1; i <= number; i++) {
        for (let j = 1; j < 11; j++) {
            oneRow += (''+(j*i)).padStart((''+number).length + 1, ' ') + " ";
        }
    console.log(oneRow);
        oneRow = '';
    } 

}

multiply(11);
```

Comment: Попробуйте ввести число больше 11.

Comment: @ΝNL993, поправил)

Comment: Благодарю вас безмерно! padStart() еще не использовал, пойду почитаю документацию.

Answer (score 1):

```js
let oneRow = '';

const multiply = (number) => {
  for (let i = 1; i <= number; i++) {
    for (let j = 1; j < 11; j++) {
      let k = j * i;
      oneRow += " ".repeat(getNumberLength(number * 10) - getNumberLength(k) + 1) + k;
    }
    console.log(oneRow);
    oneRow = '';
  } 

}

multiply(5);

function getNumberLength(n) {
  return n.toString().length
}
```

#### Объяснение к вопросу

У строк нет пропроции `style`, такая пропорция есть у элементов (`HTMLElement`), допустим: `document.body.style`, вот в этом примере `style` будет объектом со стилями, а у строк `'some str'.style` будет `undefined`, по этому и вылезала ошибка.

---

Можно конечно через стили прижать, но стили нужно вписывать в метод консоли (Способ рабочий на Firefox, в других браузерах не тестировал):

```js
let oneRow = '';

const multiply = (number) => {
  for (let i = 1; i <= number; i++) {
    for (let j = 1; j < 11; j++) {
      let k = j * i;
      oneRow += " ".repeat(getNumberLength(number * 10) - getNumberLength(k) + 1) + k;
    }
    console.log('%c' + oneRow, 'float: right;');
    oneRow = '';
  } 

}

multiply(5);

function getNumberLength(n) {
  return n.toString().length
}
```

Вот скриншот:

[image]

P.S.: Я это не вставил как воспроизводимый пример, по той причине, что консоль в StackOverflow не позволяет внедрять стили в логи.

Comment: Последний пример не работает

Comment: @Grundy здравствуйте, можете, пожалуйста, показать скриншот? Причина "не работает" не слишком помогает понять проблему.

Comment: @Grundy, спасибо за логические операторы ;-)

Comment: @Grundy исправил код, теперь столбы стоят ровно.

Comment: до редактирование: https://i.imgur.com/r4cZV3q.png и после: https://i.imgur.com/pXsxD7k.png.  Никакой разницы. Параметр `%c` ни на что не влияет у тебя и код ровно такой же стал как и без него. Ну и второй `%c` не рассматривается как параметр

Comment: @Grundy Хм, похоже, что ваш браузер не поддерживает стили в консоли. Попробуйте запустить на Firefox.

Comment: @UModeL, о каких логических операторах речь?

Comment: @Grundy, когда-то Вы своим ответом обратили моё внимание на них.

Comment: @Grundy обновил ответ, ознакомьтесь с тем как это должно выглядеть на Firefox.

Comment: @ΝNL993, [поддерживает](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/console/format-style/#style-specifier). Скорее всего конкретно `float` не поддерживается. В любом случае указывать два параметра и передавать один - не верно

Comment: @Grundy да, думаю, вы правы, раз у вас второй параметр отображается, значит он нигде не используется, соответственно он не нужен. Скорее всего, на Firefox, они просто убираются как не нужные.

Comment: Спасибо за объяснение про строки! Ученье свет!

Comment: @Станислав не за что! Вы можете ознакомиться со строками и их методами и пропорциями [на MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String).